# BlueSnap omnipay integration

Tags: payment, gateway, omnipay, bluesnap

Did anyone used or know where can I find Bluesnap omnipay gateway?
I'm working on OctoberCMS site using JIRI shop plugin.
Last integration made possible to use omnipay gateways, but bluesnap (i'm about to use) is missing. Wondering if anyone already made it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On this page is the canonical list of integrations for Omnipay:

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay

There are approximately 100 integrations there but sadly Bluesnap is not one of them.  If you contribute the gateway code then we can list it on the Omnipay page.

According to the API docs on the Bluesnap website it is a REST API that takes either SXML blobs as input.  It should not be too hard to code such a gateway based on one of the existing REST gateways, e.g. Stripe, the only complexity being the generation of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I've just created an Omnipay driver for BlueSnap. At this time, it's mostly intended for the BlueSnap Hosted Checkout product, but you could expand it for the rest of the API: https://github.com/vimeo/omnipay-bluesnap